# Recycler view not scrolling to last position

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm having an issue maybe for misunderstanding how android recyclerview scroll works. I hope this can help the community too, and if you answer please provide information about the causes and fixes in a detailed way. Thanks.

The main problem I'm having is that I have a stack from end true RecyclerView that shows firebase real-time database messages. When a child is added, removed etc I call my method display messages witch sets the adapter with the new messages list and then it scrolls to the last position. The problem is that is not scrolling to the last position as you will see in the video ill show here.

[Error video (Click here)](https://www.loom.com/share/567b19b9e1e14c34abf57005f2fa3f18)

I leave here the ChatFragment Class which is the one used. Also the layout for the ChatFragment.

ChatFragment:

```
private void setAdapter() {
    loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerViewMessageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}

private void displayMessages(List<Message> messages) {
    if (messages.size() > 0) {
        MessageAdapter messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(), messages);
        recyclerViewMessageList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        recyclerViewMessageList.scrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
    }
    loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lottieAnimationViewLoading.cancelAnimation();
}
```

fragment_chat layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.ChatFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMessageList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayoutChatInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutChatInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerViewMessageList">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextChatSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:autofillHints="@string/write_message"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/write_message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="6"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewChatSendMessage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageViewChatSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextChatSendMessage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/loading_messages_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

I have solved it by changing the order of setting the layout manager:

```
private void setAdapter() {
    loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void displayMessages(List<Message> messages) {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerViewMessageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    MessageAdapter messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(), messages);
    recyclerViewMessageList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    recyclerViewMessageList.scrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
    loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lottieAnimationViewLoading.cancelAnimation();
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500 (five hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: If possible then please put your XML code for the designing issue. That will be more convenient to solve the issue.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have reduced the first file lines to the mentioned two methods for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you do not use (on this line recyclerViewMessageList.scrollToPosition(messages.size() - 2);) the -2 because what i saw on the video it was openning on correct position but after scrolls to -2 position

Comment: Nothing it´s still doing the same.

Comment: and if you try to scroll recyclerview to it's max position??
something like recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

Comment: So then it didn't worked when you took off recyclerViewMessageList.scrollToPosition(messages.size() - 2);) and added layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)->before setting 
LayoutManager(layoutManager)?

Comment: @Àlex did you get to fix it?

Comment: I fixed it as said in the edit.